Cup products in the rational cohomology of products of spaces
I'm starting to learn cup products and I have been stuck at a problem. I need to find the cup product structure in the rational cohomology ring of $X = S^3 \times T^3$, where $S^3$ is the $3$-sphere and $T^3 = S^1 \times S^1 \times S^1$.
I know that $H^*(X;\mathbb{Q}) = H^*(S^3;\mathbb{Q}) \otimes H^*(T^3;\mathbb{Q})$ due to rational coefficients (this is not true in case of torsion). I want to understand how the cup product behaves in $H^*(X;\mathbb{Q})$? In particular, in both $H^*(S^3;\mathbb{Q})$ and $H^*(T^3;\mathbb{Q})$ individually, the cup product of any four non-zero elements of positive degree is zero: does this fact remain true in the ring $H^*(X;\mathbb{Q})$ as well? Is it possible to find $6$ non-zero elements of positive degree in $H^*(X;\mathbb{Q})$ such that their cup product is non-zero in $H^*(X;\mathbb{Q})$?
I believe the answer to the first question is yes, and that to the second question is no. The maximum size of cup product in positive degrees in $H^*(X;\mathbb{Q})$ is also $3$, as in the case of $H^*(T^3;\mathbb{Q})$. Can someone kindly confirm this?
EDIT (after the second comment): $H^*(S^3;\mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{Q}[a]/(a^2)$ for a generator $a \in H^3(S^3;\mathbb{Q})$ and $H^*(T^3;\mathbb{Q}) = \Lambda_{\mathbb{Q}}[x,y,z]$ where $x,y,z\in H^1(T^3;\mathbb{Q})$ are the generators. Then, $H^*(X;\mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{Q}[a]/(a^2) \otimes \Lambda_{\mathbb{Q}}[x,y,z]$.

What do you mean by "let $b \in H^1(T^3; \mathbb{Q})$ be the generator"? $H^1(T^3; \mathbb{Q})$ is 3-dimensional.

@BenSteffan that was a mistake. I have fixed it and made my question more precise.

Do you understand $H^(S^3; \mathbb{Q})$ and $H^(T^3; \mathbb{Q})$ as a ring? Because if you do then this question reduces to a purely algebraic one about tensor products of graded algebras. If this is the case, please write down explicit descriptions for $H^(S^3; \mathbb{Q})$ and $H^(T^3; \mathbb{Q})$ and $H^(X; \mathbb{Q})$ as (tensor products of) polynomial/alternating algebras. Otherwise, please clarify which of $H^(S^3; \mathbb{Q})$ and $H^*(T^3; \mathbb{Q})$ you don't understand, just so we can answer the "right" question :)

Another small thing: "in both $H^(S^3; \mathbb{Q})$ and $H^(T^3; \mathbb{Q})$ individually, the cup product of any four non-zero elements is zero" is false on the nose: take arbitrary cup powers of $1 \in H^0(\ldots; \mathbb{Q})$. You should either say "of any four non-zero elements in positive degree" or work with reduced cohomology.

@BenSteffan I do understand. I have edited the question again. I just want to confirm if the "cup length" of $H^*(X;\mathbb{Q})$ described above is $3$. Thanks!

I will implicitly assume $\mathbb{Q}$-coefficients for the whole answer.
It's not correct that the product of any four non-zero elements in positive degree in $H^*(X)$ is zero, but you're only off by one: the product of any five such elements is.
To see this, note that we can write the cohomology ring of $S^3$ as $\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}} H^*(S^3) \cong \Q[a] / (a^2) \cong \Lambda(a)$, so
$$
    H^*(X) = H^*(S^3 \times T^3) \cong \Lambda(a) \otimes \Lambda(x, y, z) \cong \Lambda(a, x, y, z)
$$
with $|a| = 3$ and $|x| = |y| = |z| = 1$. Then the product $a \smile x \smile y \smile z \in H^6(X)$ is a generator, in particular non-zero. On the other hand, it follows from this description that the product of any five or more terms in positive degree must be trivial since $a^2 = x^2 = y^2 = z^2 = 0$ (if it's not clear to you how this implies the claim, I think it would be a good exercise to work through the algebra).

Really the idea here is no different from computing $H^*(T^4)$ or more generally $H^*(T^n)$; you're just swapping out a copy of $S^1$ for one of $S^3$. Since $H^*(S^n) \cong \Lambda(w)$ for a class $w$ in degree $n$ for all $n$, nothing really changes when you allow different dimensional spheres, at least as long as the dimensions are all odd.

This makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much for the perfect explanation.
